# getting error file not found in spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

[image][image]I am making a simple program in spring getting this error .

```
----
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'studentbean' defined in class path resource [META-INF/test.xml]: Error setting property values; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'name' of bean class [test]: Bean property 'name' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1361)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1086)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:580)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:895)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:425)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
    at test.main(test.java:12)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'name' of bean class [test]: Bean property 'name' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.setPropertyValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:1024)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.setPropertyValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:900)
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:76)
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:58)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1358)
    ... 13 more
```

i take help of this link .
http://www.javatpoint.com/steps-to-create-spring-application
I do the following steps

create a xml in this folder WEB-INF test.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
<beans  
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"  
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"  
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans  
               http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">  

<bean id="studentbean" class="test">  
<property name="name" value="Vimal Jaiswal"></property>  
</bean>  

</beans>  


public class test {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("----");
    ApplicationContext applicationContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("META-INF/test.xml");
;   
    //BeanFactory factory=new XmlBeanFactory(appContext);  

    Student student=(Student)applicationContext.getBean("studentbean");  
    student.displayInfo(); 
}
}
```

Comment: It seems to be looking for `META-INF/test.xml` and not `WEB-INF/test.xml`.

Comment: That's not a "class not found", it's a "file not found", and it's self-explanatory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is this:

```
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [META-INF/test.xml]
```

You have not that file in your classpath..

Put your `test.xml` file into `META-INF` directory

For the new problem, in your test class you have to declare getter and setter for name property..

Comment: hmm ..I done that but I am getting same error ..I am running the java file with run as java application

Comment: please check my updates pic..I make dynamic web projet only create two java file and one xml file

Comment: Put META-INF under src folder

Comment: In your bean test you need to have setter and getter for name property :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45933/discussion-between-user944513-and-mserioli)